# How do i manipulate the clone of a draggable helper: "clone" item?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I use the following code to move a clone around the screen.

```
$(".items").draggable({helper:"clone",

  start: function(){}, 
  drag: function(){}, 
  stop: function(){}
});
```

but inside of the start/drag, i wanted to manipulate the cloned object instead of the base object, adding some text or removing some text from it.

How would i deal that that?  Is there a way to do something like:

```
start: function(){
  var $c = $(this).getClone();
  $c.text("test me");
}
```

Comment: $(this).clone() clones the object.   When you set the helper to clone it will drag a clone about, instead of the original document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're trying to accomplsih, try using the second callback parameter in the [.start(event, ui)](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) method.

```
$(".items").draggable({helper:"clone",

  start: function(event, ui){
      var clone = $(ui.helper);
      clone.text('testttttt');
  }, 
  drag: function(){}, 
  stop: function(){}
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/L9w6K/)

Comment: PERFECT.  Thats exactly what i wanted.  I keep forgetting that there are 2 args passed in those functions because i almost never use the second.  Thanks Dennis